# Convert body to pdf with html2canvas and jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, pdf, jquery-plugins

Good morning all,
I found the script which can be [convert to pdf](http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html)

His works nice, when information have into the tag `form`..

```js
(function(){
var 
 form = $('.form'),
 cache_width = form.width(),
 a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  // for a4 size paper width and height

$('#create_pdf').on('click',function(){
 $('body').scrollTop(0);
 createPDF();
});
//create pdf
function createPDF(){
 getCanvas().then(function(canvas){
  var 
  img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
  doc = new jsPDF({
          unit:'px', 
          format:'a4'
        });     
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
        form.width(cache_width);
 });
}

// create canvas object
function getCanvas(){
 form.width((a4[0]*1.33333) -80).css('max-width','none');
 return html2canvas(form,{
     imageTimeout:2000,
     removeContainer:true
    }); 
}

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>HTML to PDF - techumber</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="ui page grid">
  <div class="wide column">
   <h1 class="ui header aligned center">HTML to PDF</h1>
   <div class="ui divider hidden"></div>
   <div class="ui segment">
    <div class="ui button aligned center teal" id="create_pdf">Create PDF</div>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <form class="ui form">
     <p class="ui paragraph">oasdojasodjasjdaisjdoasjdoij</p>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- scripts -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How into the `var` in app.js code transfer to [this](http://mvd.uz/press-tsentr/novosti/item/rassmotreny-aktualnye-voprosy?tmpl=component&print=1)

my script generates any articles in print format when have after following links to article `?tmpl=component&print=1`
The question is How to transfer `?tmpl=component&print=1` to `var` instead tag `form`
maybe can try that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("a").click(function(){
          var link = $(this).attr("href");
        });

      });
```

or something like this?

**UPD!**
After the answer @Sergion Alen got this idea:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("a").click(function(){
          var link = window.location.href + '?tmpl=component&print=1';
          alert(link);
        });

      });
```

Displays what i need... How to write array `link` display here (replace class `.forms` for the array `link`) ?:

```
form = $('.form')
```

in app.js

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Could you please try to explain in more detail

Comment: @SergioAlen I want to make a link to download a pdf file of each article after title name... when click to link must started to download article which have in last link (that is `http://mvd.uz/press-tsentr/novosti/item/rassmotreny-aktualnye-voprosy` added this `?tmpl=component&print=1`)

Comment: @SergioAlen in link `http://mvd.uz/press-tsentr/novosti/item/rassmotreny-aktualny‌​e-voprosy` near title have link icon `PRINT` when you click this, your browser open `http://mvd.uz/press-tsentr/novosti/item/rassmotreny-aktualny‌​e-voprosy` with `?tmpl=component&print=1` this.. I want to pass this link to the pdf generator

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right track then, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    document.location = link + '?tmpl=component&print=1';
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, please see UPD question... i'm getting `window.location.href`